# In browser conversion of svg to png image (cross browser including IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts

I am using Highcharts and i need to convert all the charts on the page to an image that i can send to my server so i can merge it to a master export excel which already contains some tables and pivot grids.
This is my code so far

```
var svg = Highcharts.getSVG(charts);
img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svg);
mycanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
mycanvas.width = 1000
mycanvas.height = 1000
ctx = mycanvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
$("body").append("<image src='" + mycanvas.toDataURL("image/png") + "'/>");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("getfile")',
    data: JSON.stringify({ file: mycanvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("data:image/png;base64,", "") }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

This is the c# code where i tested if i get the data correctly from the client(i just write the base64 string to a file). Firefox and Chrome write the image correctly, IE just give me a black image

```
public void getfile(string file)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\yourfile.png", Convert.FromBase64String(file));
}
```

the entire code you can find here
http://jsfiddle.net/gd7bB/2291/

The image seems to be generated fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not IE(here i just get a black image). I am using a canvas which from what i gathered IE supports [IE9 Support for HTML5 Canvas tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016513/ie9-support-for-html5-canvas-tag).

If you could help me figure out what i'm doing wrong, or maybe you can point the way of a better solution i would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE9 seem to indeed support the canvas element as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ff975241(v=vs.85).aspx

The following sample/test code for toDataURL works for me in IE11 : http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/Workshop/samples/canvas/todataurl.html

The fiddle you gave does not work in IE11 ; looking at the console errors, it leads to the fact that you cannot call drawImage before the image has finished its rendering. IE Throws a

call to unsupported method or attributes of a method

Adding a setTimeout allow IE to render the dynamic image and bypass this error.

But it then leads to a

```
Security Error
```

because it seems that IE has tainted the canvas because of some "cross origin" issue

```
SecurityError
The img or video element is not of the same origin or domain
as the document that owns the canvas element. Versions earlier
than Internet Explorer 10 use SECURITY_ERR.
```

IE seems to be tainting all images filled with SVG for security reasons - [SVG tained canvas IE security error toDataURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364396/svg-tained-canvas-ie-security-error-todataurl)

I managed to have a working version using `canvg`, which transforms an SVG file into canvas instructions - https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg

the solution boils down to

```
var svg = Highcharts.getSVG(charts);
var mycanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvg(mycanvas, svg)
console.log(mycanvas.toDataURL("image/png"))
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6bxqbaeb/1/ which works in IE11

Comment: i tried leaving only the call from the ajax, but still the same, the link you gave me also works in my IE9, so i guess i'll try to look at code there see what i did different, thanks, i'll let you know

Comment: I added a proposed solution. I think there is no easy solution because of the way IE handles SVG and cross origin policies. If canvg supports your set of svg elements, it will I think work for you problem

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. The conclusion i came to is that IE9 does not support image sources of type svg (ie: data:image/svg+xml)